# Maven release plugin throwing Hostname Not found exception?

Tags: networking, maven

I am trying to release a project in jenkins and getting a host not found exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.generateDefaultClientspecName(PerforceScmProvider.java:420)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.getClientspecName(PerforceScmProvider.java:395)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.checkout.PerforceCheckOutCommand.executeCheckOutCommand(PerforceCheckOutCommand.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkout.AbstractCheckOutCommand.executeCommand(AbstractCheckOutCommand.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
```

Reading through the source it looks like the exception is thrown on this line:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Since I don't control the source for the release plugin other than changeing the code is there some way to work around this issue? Can I setup my etc hosts in some way to force specific response from "InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is masking an actual, non-localhost (or localhost variant/alias) hostname.

This can happen if your machine has a hostname/IP-address that cannot be both forward and reverse looked-up according to your local name resolver setup.  `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` is known to perform reverse lookups to resolve the local host.

Run the `hostname` command, and make sure that you have an entry matching your real IP address to that name in `/etc/hosts`.  It may be that `hostname` is returning either the FQDN hostname or the alias/short hostname, and that these cannot be forward/reverse looked-up.

Another problem can be IPv6 versus IPv4.

Note that the Jenkins JVM will cache hostname lookups, so it pays to have a small test program to make the test call to `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`, otherwise you should restart Jenkins after each configuration change you test.

Please provide feedback/additional details so I can improve this answer.

Comment: It was actually that the hostname command was returning a hostname which was not the DNS hostname. I fixed it by setting hostname to match DNS.